# Animation from spritesheet out of phase in Unity

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite-sheet, shake

I'm using the sprite editor from Unity to load spritesheets as animations. I don't know why the sprites end up being out of phase, causing a shake effect during the animation.

Here's one of the spritesheets

[Idle animation spritesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qefER.png)

Here's how it looks loaded in unity

[Idle animation in Unity](http://gph.is/2p0PADT)

I have already tried if the spritesheet is correct in this website: http:// is.si/animator/ , and it is (configuration is 432 x 407 per frame, 25 frames and frame time 1).

I give it a try in a blank project, and it has the same problem

Note: the configuration in Unity's sprite editor is 5 columns, 5 rows (by cell count), or 432x407 (by cell size). The pivot doesn't matter, I have the same error using any pivot position.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I found what the problem was. The spritesheet were bigger than 2048 (in the width), and by default Unity compress all textures to 2048. So the compressed image wasn't divisible by 5 anymore.
I solve it by setting the compression to 4096 (size don't matter becouse all the blank space gets eliminated when using sprite packer).